# How to get backtrace of main thread?

Tags: ios, backtrace

I am an iOS Developer. I want to get the mainThread stack on runtime. I found some tools, For ex. plcrashreport, etc. But, these tools get backtraces only from active thread, and the implementation is complex. So, I want to know if there is another way to get mainThread backtraces? Using runloop or any other way?

Comment: PS:[NSThread callstackSymbols] only can get the current thread.I want to snaping main thread stack while in other thread.please help me,thank you!

Comment: Backtrace is basicaly callstack of current thread e.g. adressess on stack in reverse order. But addresses are just numbers. So u need to symbolicate them somehow. Yes, crash reporters are doing this and it is good idea of diving into theris code. Actually I know 2 of them are opensourced - PL, KSCrash.